# Is The Facebook "Keep your account secure" Checkpoint Authentic?

Tags: privacy, facebook

I don't use Facebook often, but I'm logged in all the time on my primary browser, so I can access it whenever I want.

A few weeks ago I was on my timeline, browsing and making the occasional comment, when after clicking on the Facebook logo to refresh my timeline, I'm shown a screen to log in.

I thought it was strange, but I proceeded to log in only to be shown a strange screen asking me to do several tasks. I can't remember what I clicked, but now, when I log in, I'm shown this page:

[image: Facebook]

So, I continue to a Reset Password page, but I'm reluctant to do so incase there is something wrong with this - It doesn't seem right to me, and I've searched for similar cases, but find none.

Has anyone else encountered this? What's the best way to proceed and stay secure?

Comment: That green padlock icon, combined with the correct URL `https://www.facebook.com...` is a very strong indication that this page is authentic. Read up on https and certificates if you want to know why.

Answer (score 1):

This is random security check done by Facebook. They do it when they feel any suspicious or unusual activity which includes changes in profile, network setting, new internet connection, new browser, all of sudden so many activity, no activity for a longer time, etc..

Proceed with the screen instructions, they will confirm from you about few of last activities/changes. Once you are done with it everything will be fine.

They do it for security check where user needs to confirm that all the activities has been done by him/her.

Answer (score -1):

This page may appear for the following eight reasons:

1. Fake account: You are not using your real name.
2. Joined groups: You have joined too many groups. Each user is limited to a maximum of 200 groups.
3. Spam: If you post too many messages in too short a time, you can treat them as spam.
4. Friends: You may have too many friends. Facebook has developed up to 5,000 friends.
5. Offensive content: You wrote something that is offensive.
6. Frequency: You may have sent "too many" friend requests or "too many" posts (especially the same content) in a short period of time.
7. Hacked: Someone may try to access your account, so Facebook needs you to verify who you are.
8. Malware.

So to avoid being banned or verifying your account, you need to:

1. Continue to interact with friends on Facebook
2. Limit friend requests and the number of posts you post in a short period of time
3. Must abide by the terms and conditions, Facebook random review is still very strict